# how to properly use getComponants to get a audio array?

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Alright, so I got this code I shrunk down to one line:

```
gameObject.GetComponents(AudioSource)[0].audio.Play();
```

This line gives me this error:

```
InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
scriptexplosion+$Start$4+$.MoveNext () (at Assets/scriptexplosion.js:7)
```

My question is how do I turn the array of Components into an array of AudioSource?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you got to use this code to make GetComponents() to return the type (In this case, AudioSource):

```
gameObject.GetComponents<AudioSource>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
gameObject.GetComponents(AudioSource[0]).audio.Play();
```

Comment: That one gave me this: Assets/scriptexplosion.js(7,34): BCE0048: Type 'System.Type' does not support slicing.
It was a good idea though.